# How to sell several apps sharing vars in App Store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm struggeling with a problem.

I want to sell one app in AppStore. But, I want to sell it by parts.

For example, you can buy one football team, and later, buy each player separately. I thought share vars between several apps, but I dont know if it's possible.

Can anyone help me? Where can I take information about that?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Solved thanks of one collegue: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Overview%20of%20the%20Store%20Kit%20API/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about that, too. I know it's weird to answer your own question, but to get this off the unanswered list, you should put your EDIT into an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution "Apple -In App Purchase":
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Getting Started document:
http://developer.apple.com/news/ios/pdf/in_app_purchase.pdf

Sample code:
http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/